# Executing commands from a process running under a nologin user

Tags: bash, nologin

I have a process that runs under a nologin user (in this case [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) server).

I would like to execute some shell commands from that process but most of them are not available apart from standard utilities like `ls`, `date` etc...

In my particular case I want to use some scripts that are available in `/usr/local` and for normal login users it's enough to just `source` an init script in `.bashrc`

`source` for nologin users doesn't seem to be working as well as the `.` operator.

I've tried adding the necessary lines to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` but that also doesn't work.

Is there any other way than just copying the binaries into `/bin` ?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/usr/local` to `ENV_PATH` in `/etc/login.defs`, because The `/etc/login.defs` file contains a default path as follows:

```
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this won't be helpful in my case. I have the following lines in my own `.bashrc : export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`
This adds commands that are available for normal users but my nologin process doesn't execute that (he even cannot do that) thus cannot run the commands. Is there any way around this?